Error while evaluating the model. Verify that the serialized input Dataframe is compatible with the model for inference. I am using SDV ctgan model
class Model_Wrapper(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):

    def __init__(self,):
      self.model = None

    def load_context(self,context):
        self.model=mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(context.artifacts["Original_Model"])

    def predict(self, context, model_input):
       ss = self.model.sample(int(model_input.get("records")[0]))
       return ss.to_json()


input format:
invocations url  post method : {"inputs":{"records":[2]}}

error screenshot
Input to the invocation url is as expected and in the format of mlflow keywords.
Output expected is dataframe.

Use the code as it is... don't do any changes:
 def predict(self, context, model_input):                                                                    
    tempPath = f"temp.{model_input.get("records")[0]}.csv"
     ss = self.model.sample(int(model_input.get("records")[0]),output_file_path=tempPath)
     if os.path.exists(tempPath):
           os.remove(tempPath)                                                                                                                                                                                 
     return ss.to_json()

